# Incorrect sources.list causing apt-get update to fail Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu

I was trying to install ruby using the rvm and it was failing due to a problem with apt-get update. I discovered that this is caused by problems with the sources.list file in the etc/apt directory. I tried to use this http://blog.ubuntu-tweak.com/guide/how-to-fix-the-source-list-files to understand and fix my sources file. By the time I had removed the "bad lines" from the sources.list, there were no lines left. At this point I was able to apt-get update successfully, but rvm install ruby was still failing because it now wasn't able to locate the necessary dependencies. I'm starting to consider a complete fresh install because I have no idea what else to do, but I figured I would ask for help here first.

**sources.list**

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130424)]/ raring main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
```

**Console Output**

```
erik@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security Release.gpg          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg                     
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release.gpg
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security Release               
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports Release.gpg        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release                          
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release                       
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages              
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports Release            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages               
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en              
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en_US   
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en      
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en      
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like you're using Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail) and it is no longer supported since Jan 27, 2014.

In case you don't want to update yet, you could also replace both `archive.ubuntu.com` and `security.ubuntu.com` with `old-releases.ubuntu.com` in your `sources.list` file (may be simply use the script I [wrote](https://gist.github.com/zdk/875c9fdf3ef588b2e792) that does the same thing automatically)

[Updated] as @wes-johnson states in the comment, I removed `dist-upgrade` because it will use the old source and doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Changing the sources in `sources.list` worked for me. The wrong sources seemed to prevent me from doing `dist-upgrade` anyways.